# How to solve Modal popup not closing

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

On my project page, I'm displaying projects in cards and when you click the card, a modal pops up with details about the project. This is the same with the "Services" page. Everything works well on the services page.

On the projects page, the modal opens but won't close when I click the background or the cancel icon. The modal component receives a single prop so we can close the modal as soon as it's open. The codes look like this.

###### Project Page

```js
...
const [crowdfundingIsOpen, setCrowdfundingIsOpen] = useState(false);
...

<div className="img-card-container" onClick={() => setCrowdfundingIsOpen(true)}>
  <div className="img-card">
    <div className="overlay"></div>
    <div className="info">
      <h3>Crowd Funding</h3>
      <span>Personal</span>
    </div>
    <img src={projectPreview} alt="" />
  </div>
  {crowdfundingIsOpen && (
    <CrowdfundingModal setCrowdfundingIsOpen={setCrowdfundingIsOpen} />
  )}
</div>;
```

The code above is supposed to trigger opening the modal when I click the `card-card-container` div, then we pass a single prop to `CrowdfundingModal`, and up to this point, everything works fine.

On CrowdfundingModal below, `onClick={() => setCrowdfundingIsOpen(false)}` is NOT working. It's supposed to set state back to false hence closing the modal but when i click on the background and the close Icon nothing happens. There is no error in the console. When I and `console.log("Clicked")` it returns clicked.

What could be the issue?

###### CrowdfundingModal

```js
const CrowdfundingModal = ({ setCrowdfundingIsOpen }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.darkBG} onClick={() => setCrowdfundingIsOpen(false)}>
      <div className={styles.centered}>
        <div className="projects-model-body">
          <i
            className={styles.closeBtn}
            onClick={() => setCrowdfundingIsOpen(false)}
          >
            <FaTimes style={{ marginBottom: "-3px" }} />
          </i>
          <div> Modal Body goes here</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove onClick on styles.darkBG div

.<div className={styles.darkBG} onClick={() => setCrowdfundingIsOpen(false)}

or add

onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} to styles.centered div

Comment: I did it like this: 
```const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setCrowdfundingIsOpen(false);
  };```
Then ```onClick={handleClick}``` and it works. WHY?

In my Service Modals the code above works just fine. But in my Project modals I needed to do this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I need to see your Service Modal but you used two nested "setCrowdfundingIsOpen(false)" methods and that's why it's not working. We blocked the insider function with e.StopPropagation(). It may be healthier if you remove it completely.